# Getting the maximum of values in Cognos in a Query

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I have a query which consists of 3 columns,

ID, Name, Start Date

Each ID has 2 or more start dates. The start date might be having the same value for some ID's say for eg: Id 281 contains start dates as 12-03-2011 12:00:00 and 12-03-2011 12:00:00. I need to get the maximum of the start date for each ID using the rownumber concept. But I'm not able to do. Could you please help me with your solutions on how to solve it

Comment: Hi Saraban - Welcome to SO. Could you please provide us with what you have tried so far, and what errors you received? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info.

Answer (score 1):

you can build the report the way you need it and then add a filter of [start date] = maximum([start date] for [ID]) and that will filter the report to show only the max start date rows. if it is in a list report though and you have the ID before the start date you can leave the (for [ID]) out.

Hope this helps!